# Returning mock objects with Mockito using given arguments

Tags: mockito, junit4, junit5

For my JUnit Tests with Mockito, I am doing the following:

```
    Mockito.lenient().when(tokenService.create(String id, Any)).thenReturn(new String (id))

    Mockito.lenient().when(voucherRepo.findById(id String).thenReturn(new Voucher(id));
```

I would like to access the String id given to tokenService.create() and voucherRepo.findById() methods, create and then return mock objects using it. How it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

```java
Mockito.when(voucherRepo.findById(id)).thenReturn(new Voucher(id));
```

Your solution should work and is probably the preferred solution for any clear defined test.
As you know in your test what the exact `id` is, you can just return the specific object for it.

Another way to do this - for arbitrary strings - is using mockito's `thenAnswer` funtionality:

```java
Mockito.when(voucherRepo.findById(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<Voucher>() {

    @Override
    public Voucher answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {

        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        String id = (String) args[0];
        return new Voucher(id);
    }
});
```

I am not sure what reason you have to do that in your test (as this a rather arbitrary defintion), but in doubt consider adding some more context to your question.